# How to auto populate apex form field

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am creating a profile page in oracle apex and I am having troubles populating the form fields with values from the user table. I created a before header process with the plsql code

```
select user_id, fname, lname, email
into :P15_USER_ID, :P15_FNAME, :P15_LNAME, :P15_EMAIL
from user
where email = :APP_USER;
```

However, I got an error message saying no data was found and I can't seem to figure out why even after debugging. Any idea why this might happen?

Alternatively, I tried replacing `:app_user` with `v('app_user')` as well but the same thing happened.

If anyone has any references on how to autofill a form in apex it would be of great help to me as well. Thank you for any inputs in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably reason is that there is no record in the `user` table with a record where email *exactly matches* the value of :APP_USER. This means: (1) that case needs to be the same ('mickey.mouse@disney.com' is not the same as 'Mickey.Mouse@disney.com') and (2) there can not be any blanks in the email column (' mickey.mouse@disney.com' is not the same as 'mickey.mouse@disney.com'). So the question is: what value is there in the column email and what value is there in APP_USER ?

As second possibility is that this no data found exception is not raised by the statement you posted but by another statement. This should be visible in debug.

Note: in the context of an apex session, :APP_USER and v('APP_USER') should have identical values. The only difference is that the 'v' function fetches the value from the apex session metadata and the :APP_USER is a native pl/sql bind variable (and is more performant).

Comment: Thank you, I managed to fix the error based on the 1st case. As for your other comment, I've marked some answers in the other questions I've asked before. Will remember to do so next time! The reason why I didn't do so in the past was most likely because I didn't get the error fixed and was leaving the question open for more answers/advices.